# Is Goku an irresponsible person, who always puts other's lives in danger?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball

Leaving power levels aside, is Goku if not worst, one of the worst anime characters?

To support this question, I have several examples:

- He has put everyone in danger many times, just to have fun fighting.
- He spared Piccolo, who was the manifestation of Kami's malice (later he turned out to be a good character), but that was a huge risk comparing Piccolo's power to humans.
- He let go of Raditz and Vegeta in their fight, who could've destroyed the planet, as it's Saiyans' job.
- He gave his energy to Frieza, who later came to destroy the earth, which would've been destroyed if not for Trunks.
- In Cell Saga, he gives Cell a Senzu-Bean, as if fair fighting is more important than the survival of the planet.
- He wasn't seriously fighting with Beerus when all of the Z-fighters were requesting him to save the planet.
- He messes around Beerus and Zeno who can destroy planets or universes in a jiffy.
- He kickstarted the *Tournament of Power*, putting the entire multiverse's existence at stake, just because he wanted to fight someone.

Other than putting other's life at risk.

- He didn't care about his own family, he spent most of his life training rather than spending it with his family.

EDIT: Changed the question title (Villain -> Irresponsible) to better relay my question.

Comment: He did not let go of Raditz: he actually enabled his murder by sacrificing himself. Then Piccolo screws up by boasting that they a magical wish-granting dragon, which Nappa and Vegeta overhear, prompting them to come to Earth.

Comment: for Raditz, it was when he lied that he'd surrender, and Goku let go of his tail after catching him. That is only one of the points though.

Comment: "He didn't care about his own family, he spent most of his life training rather than spending it with his family.", well, that would need some measurement. If we take DBZ, I'd say say he spent most of time **dead**. He married at the end of DB, he reappears 5 years later with a son (which he has lived with), then he's dead for a year, then he goes to a hospital, then he goes to Namek, then he takes 1 year to come back (could have done it sooner), then he stays with his family for 3 years while training (because he has to), then he would be dead for good, if not for the events 6 years later.

Comment: @Gae.S., you're right, I mean for the family part, he can ask others to call Shenron and revive him anytime, but he only comes back when there's a strong opponent.

Comment: It sounds like bad judgment and not a villain

Comment: @JoeW, I am not talking about his character, I am talking about putting other's life at risk.

Comment: @Zero Well, he gives his reason for staying dead, which you may or may not agree with, but having the option to be resurrected doesn't really make you a dick if you stay dead. Death is still a part of life in DBZ.

Comment: Again that sounds like bad judgment and not a villain. People can make stupid and dangerous choices but that doesn’t mean that they are a villain

Comment: You're also missing a passage about Frieza: 1) Goku gives him energy. 2) Frieza says "Don't pity me" and attacks him. 3) *Goku makes his best, and to his knowledge successful, attempt at murdering him.* 4) Unbeknownst to him and everybody else, Frieza managed to survive and be rescued by his father.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I were to write an answer for "irresponsible" (and I might not have the time to do it) by arguing that "reckless" is a better adjective, are you going to change the question once more to "reckless"?

Comment: Nope, @Gae.S., I just couldn't find the exact words in my first try.

Comment: @Gae.S. to be fair, for the most time he ***wanted*** to stay dead.... in order to freely train without Chichi interference. He later pulls out the excuse "it is better if I stay dead because I attract villains" only to not care about that as soon as he can participate in a tournament (and wonder what? they cause the return of Majin Bu). In Dragon Ball getting out of afterlife is as simple as making a "phone call" to Shenron (even the time to get the spheres has been powercreept ), if he cared he could have asked to be wished back.

Comment: Alaz, Zero, imho the real problem is that Goku has very distinctive traits of a Mary Sue and Author Pet. Nothing he does is ever considered bad, even the Tournament of Power is hand-waved at just him being silly. The other universes are mad at him... but the show portraits them as if THEY are the one at fault (how DARED Bergamo an Top say Goku is bad?). In the meantime it is kinda implied that Goku never even considered using the Super Dragon Balls to try to save someone - something that *VEGETA* himself had planned (at least for universe 6)

Comment: That was exactly my point, @SPArcheon

Comment: Compare Dragon Ball's kid Goku with Dragon Ball Z's Goku - you go from someone that wanted to improve himself but was not fond of violence to someone with a single track mind "fightfightfighttrainfightgetpowerbostfightfightfight". BTW, you forgot that he also wanted Golden Frieza to leave and return "for a rematch", maybe after murdering a planet or two for training. He gets shot, Vegeta comes and tries to do defeat him but since he only exist to show that "Goku is Best in anime universe" he fails and Goku saves the day again. Because Goku can. He is Best.

Comment: @SPArcheon I'm familiar with chapter 417, DBZ episode 192 and DBZ KAI episode 92. I'm unaware of a source where Goku's reasoning is laid out in the order you said, i.e. him lying about his belief that Earth would be safer without him in order to slip away from his family and train. If you have one, please indicate it to me. I stand by my point that, despite availability of miracles, death, even if by violence, is the final condition for the living in DB world, and by the conclusions that I've drawn from that.

Comment: @Gae.S. In KAI ep. **97** (92 is simply too early) he states that ["it is better if I stay dead since I seem to attract bad guy"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dffPM.png). In the same episode he should also say [this ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMO7H.png) soon afterward, which betrays another reasoning. Or at least he does in the manga as you can see in the linked panels.

Comment: It is also worth noticing that while he MAY think that Gohan is strong enough to protect the world while he is not there this is also the same arc where someone future was turned in hell and his son mutilated then killed because he died and could not help. And in the present era his son was almost NOT able to kill Cell alone, it took some weird "Father&Son Kamehameha" to save him. Then the same son would no longer train, with Goku aware of this (he points that out in Bu saga) and he still does not come back to ensure that the new "hero" will be able to defend earth.

Comment: That was very much possible because Gohan was way stronger than anyone else during Cell Arc, and even Vegeta and Trunks had surpassed Goku. Which also explains why he wanted to train more while staying dead. Your second image clearly states that he was looking forward to getting stronger and Gohan is there to protect earth, and there's no point about family anytime though.

Comment: @SPArcheon I must have mis-counted the KAI episode. Leaving aside for a second your personal disagreement with Goku, I think you must agree that in the source you have (chapter 417) Goku 's full statement is: 1) He believes Earth to have a better shot a safety with him dead; 2) That he is not to be grieved over, because he is going to be in his personal paradise; 3) That he leaves Earth in Gohan's capable hands, who is now ready to succeed him. Moreover, it seems to me that you should also agree that the sanity of his reasoning is unchallenged, if not agreed upon, by the people around him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're talking about fiction, acting irresponsible and stupid does not disqualify one from being a hero, nor does it make one a villain. Being incredibly monstrous or neglectful to your own family does not automatically make a character a villain either. Just consider the story of the Greek hero Heracles. As we all know, he killed his whole family. He spends the rest of the story doing crazy tasks for a selfish king as penance. Heracles was considered a hero by the Greeks and he's still considered a hero [now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_(1997_film)). Where parenting is concerned, Goku seems pretty harmless by comparison. He may have gotten his sons and wife killed, but he never killed them himself (not in the current timeline anyway, though the whole Zamasu thing is actually quite analogous to Hera sending madness down on Heracles).

Whether a character is hero or villain all depends on the framing of the story, as well as the heroic traits that are valued in the culture the story comes from.

Oftentimes in fiction, the terms hero and villain are synonymous with protagonist and antagonist (not always, but often). In *Dragon Ball*, *Dragon Ball Z*, and *Dragon Ball Super*, I think it's pretty clear Goku is the hero and our protagonist. The story does not portray him as a villain - just a careless idiot who sometimes gets carried away wanting to fight strong opponents.

As to addressing your specific matters in your bulleted list:

1. Goku is a warrior and he likes fighting. These are not inherently villainous traits. Look at all the heroic warrior stories we have: Beowulf, Heracles, Achilles, etc. Achilles's selfishness gets his friend killed, but he's still considered a hero in spite of having this negative trait.
2. 3. 4. Mercy and forgiveness are not considered a villainous trait. They are considered heroic traits. The consequences of the forgiveness don't really matter for determining a hero. Batman is still considered a hero even though he keeps showing Joker mercy, which results in more people dying.
3. Giving Cell a Senzu Bean was idiotic and irresponsible. Those traits don't make Goku a villain. 6. and 7. are just Goku being stupid and/or irreverent too. Doesn't make him a villain.
4. I have more to say about the Tournament of Power below.
5. "He didn't care about his own family." This is not true. You could say he is neglectful, though there are some who would contend this too. I won't, though. It doesn't matter whether he's a good father and husband or not, as I've already explained.

### Definitions

Let's look at some definitions of hero and villain from Merriam Webster.

[Hero](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hero):

> a mythological or legendary figure often of divine descent
> endowed with great strength or ability
>
> an illustrious warrior
>
> a person admired for achievements and noble qualities
>
> one who shows great courage.
>
> the principal character in a literary or
> dramatic work

Nowhere in there does it say Goku has to take only good actions, or that he is not allowed to take evil actions. And note that with how ambiguous the world is, it would take a philosopher to figure out what is good and evil anyway. For instance, is it really evil to give Frieza a second chance? We have the hindsight of knowing he won't reform, but Goku doesn't.

[Villain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/villain):

> 1 : a character in a story or play who opposes the hero
>
> 2 : a deliberate scoundrel or criminal
>
> 3 : one blamed for a particular evil
>
> 4 : villein
>
> 5 : an uncouth person : boor

These ones are worth going through, which is why I've kept the numbers in. Goku definitely is not 1, because he is the hero of the story. He is not 2 either, because none of the evil he does is deliberate. But for 3-5, there is actually a case for each one that Goku is a villain.

3. Many of the other universes blame Goku for the Tournament of Power.
4. We've seen Goku do some farming in *Dragon Ball Super*, so go ahead and call him a villain. He most likely does not actually have a lord though. Or maybe the land he lives on actually belongs to the Ox King.
5. Goku has been shown to have poor manners at times.

### Conclusion

Is Goku a villain? It depends on what you mean. There are some who considered him a villain for a time, namely those from the other universes forced to participate in the Tournament of Power. As you say you believe Goku is "the worst", however, I do not think this is what you mean by villain, in which case, I think we have to conclude that he is not one. We can reasonably conclude he is a hero though, as he fits most of the definitions provided.

If the question is whether Goku is a boorish peasant though, then the answer is yeah, kind of. Though he probably doesn't fit the literal definition of a peasant, he fits the bill enough that it makes sense to use that as an insult against him.

Comment: Your answer has valid points backed by good examples, and I agree with most of them. I think I should have meant something other than a villain, as my point was that he's irresponsible, even when other's lives are at stake. So, can't say if giving Senzu beans is kind or foolish.